# Aligning buttons in Javafx layouts

Tags: java, javafx-2

I would like to align my button so that the first button is on the left of the screen and the other two are on the right. I am currently using HBox to try to position them but i cannot seem to able to figure out how to lay them out properly. The code below is what i am using now.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonTest extends Application {
    private Button min, close, openfile;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Button Test");
        Group root = new Group();
        BorderPane borderpane = new BorderPane();
        setUpButtons();
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        hbox.getChildren().add(openfile);
        HBox hbox1 = new HBox(); 
        hbox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        hbox1.getChildren().addAll(min, close);

        hbox.getChildren().add(hbox1);
        HBox.setHgrow(hbox1, Priority.ALWAYS); 
        borderpane.setTop(hbox);
        root.getChildren().add(borderpane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,600);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("button.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    private void setUpButtons() {
        close = new Button("x");
        close.setId("closeBtn");

        min = new Button("_");
        min.setId("minBtn");

        openfile = new Button("Open file");
        openfile.setId("openFileBtn");


    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the aligment of your outer HBox (hbox) to LEFT, and the aligment of your inner HBox (hbox1) to RIGHT.

Then you can have outer content on the left, and inner content on the right.

*EDIT: got your problem now. Stop using Group and add the borderpane directly to the Scene:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(borderpane,800,600);
```